# VB in Access 2013 not returning the desired result

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am currently in the process of migrating an ADP 2010 access database to an accdb 2013 and have run into an issue.

One of the functions of the database is that a user can query callouts based on a date period and employee name. This would then export to a word document claim form.

We use two recordsets to obtain this info, one rst_callouts (individual callouts) and the other rst_standby (stand by dates i.e. Monday-Friday).

The word template contains a table which details the following information: Date From and To, Description of call out, Daily Rate, No of Days claimed and the total.

rst_standy inputs the information without issue, however, the rst_callouts only exports the rate, days claims and the total. It misses the dates from and to and the description.

I have reworked the script and it’s identical to the rst_standy yet it’s still not playing ball. I have even run the query in SQL and it returns the results so I know the ADOB.recordset is also working. Any help with this would be appreciated as its driving me around the bend.

```
    ' Get all newly raised Changes using 'rst_callouts'
    ' -------------------------------------------------------------
    rst_callouts.Open "SELECT * FROM [dbo_qry_callout] " & _
                        "WHERE DateOfCallout >= #" & Format(StartDate, "mm/dd/yy#") & _
                             " AND DateOfCallout <= #" & Format(EndDate, "mm/dd/yy#") & _
                             " AND fk_StaffID = " & StaffID & _
                             " ORDER BY DateOfCallout;", con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    If rst_callouts.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rst_callouts.MoveFirst
        rst_callouts.MoveLast
        int_num_callouts = rst_callouts.RecordCount
        rst_callouts.MoveFirst
    End If


    ' This loop calculates all of the callouts to be used in the claim form
    ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    For callout_looper = 1 To int_num_callouts
        dummy_value = acbUpdateMeter(((int_num_standbys + callout_looper) / (int_num_standbys + int_num_callouts)) * 100)

        With appWord
            **.Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(rst_callouts!DateOfCallout, "dd/mm/yy")
            .Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            .Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(rst_callouts!DateOfCallout, "dd/mm/yy")
            .Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            .Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(rst_PriceList![PriceListDescription]) & " - #" & (rst_callouts!pk_CalloutID)**
            .Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            .Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(rst_PriceList![DailyRate], "0.00")
            .Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            .Selection.TypeText Text:="1"
            .Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            .Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(rst_PriceList![TotalRate], "0.00")
            .Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1
            .Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell
        End With

        ClaimTotal = ClaimTotal + rst_PriceList![TotalRate]
        rst_callouts.MoveNext
    Next callout_looper

    With appWord
        .Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell, Count:=5
        .Selection.MoveDown
        .Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(ClaimTotal, "0.00")
        .Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
        .Selection.Cells.Delete ShiftCells:=wdDeleteCellsEntireRow
    End With
```

Comment: I don't know if *anyone* is going to read through all this code for you. It may help if you can isolate the problem and edit your post with less code for people to assist you with.

Comment: Amended as requested

Comment: did you test that the fields are indeed coming into the recordset? It's hard to know if the problem is that they aren't coming into the recordset or if they just are not being inputted into the Word cell.

Comment: I ran the query in SQL and this opened up the data exactly how i wanted it. Unfortunately im more of a fixer than a scripter and wouldnt know how i would visually check that the actual recordset is open and contains the data i want it to.  However i did amend the script to tell me if the number of callouts were greater than zero to play a message and it did so im assuming it has the figures.  if the If int_num_standbys = 0 Or int_num_callouts >= 0 Then. Now the problem with the input into word sequence is that my standby script is configured exactly like the callouts and this inputs into word.

Comment: You can loop through fields in your recordset via `Do Until rst_callouts.EOF debug.print rst_callouts.Fields(i).Name debug.print rst_callouts.Field(i).Value rst_callouts.MoveNext Loop` In this way you can see in the Immediate what fields and values are in the recordset. Keep in mind `i` represents the nth field in the recordset.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thank you for the response. We have scripted the debug to run as follows.  Dim i  i = 0 Do Until rst_callouts.EOF Debug.Print rst_callouts.Fields.Item(i).Name Debug.Print rst_callouts.Fields.Item(i).Value rst_callouts.MoveNext  i = i + 1 Loop

Comment: The debug came back with 10 records with field names but the records are blank. This is now even more baffling as before if we run the SELECT query in SQL it runs and shows the records.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Scott for you help it was much appreciated and got me on the right track. I resolved this by removing DAO references and making the ADO a priority. I then had to remove my ODBC and drop all SQL tables. I than recreated the ODBC and reimported all my linked tables and its now working. Damn that was one issue that had me on the ropes, again many thanks for helping resolve this.

Comment: Great that you got it solved :) Everything is an opportunity to learn in more and more detail ...  Happy coding to you :)